# "and so on", "or something like that", "or whatever" Are they interchangeable?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'd like to know if I can use these three phrases: "*and so on*", "*or something like that*" and "*or whatever*" interchangeably in affirmative sentences.

1) Yesterday I had wine, beer *and son on*.
 2) Yesterday I had wine, beer *or something like that*.
 3) Yesterday I had wine, beer *or whatever*.

How about in question sentences?  Can I use "*or something like that*" and "*or whatever*" interchangeably?

1) Would you like tea, coffee *or something like that*?
2) Would you like tea, coffee *or whatever*?

If there is a difference in meaning, could you explain that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Yesterday I had wine, beer **and so on**.

*and so on* means there are probably other items that could have been listed, but weren't. It is something like "etc."

> Yesterday I had wine, beer or **something like that**.

*something like that* means similar items. This could be any alcoholic drink, for example.

> Yesterday I had wine, beer or **whatever**.

This is an idiomatic usage of *whatever*. It implies you don't want to make a decision or choice. another example:

> Would you like coffee or tea?  **Whatever**.

*whatever* meaning anything is fine.

Comment: Everything is very clear now.   Thank you very much.